# how to choose first row when use group by in web2py

Tags: database, web2py

I have a table in db. and when i use this code

`results = db().select(db.project.ALL, orderby=db.project.id, groupby=db.project.status)`

I can only choose the last row in repeats. how could i choose the first one?

Answer (score 1):

The `select()` method will return a `Rows` object, which is a itterable collection of `Row` objects. The order of which rows will apear in your `results` variable will vary depending on your `orderby` parameter passed to your `select()` method. If you simply want to get a single record, which is the first one out of your `select()`, you could change the above code to:

```
results = db().select(db.project.ALL, orderby=db.project.id, groupby=db.project.status).first()
```

But if your intent is to reverse the order of which you're getting the rows in result, add the tilde operator (`~`) to your `orderby` parameter, which will result in adding a `ORDER BY ____ DESC` in relational databases. Eg:

```
results = db().select(db.project.ALL, orderby=~db.project.id, groupby=db.project.status)
```